# Date format is changing when i extracting data from SQL to excel - how to stop the auto conversion

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

When I use the below python code to extract the data from SQL to excel the date format is changing automatically in the excel file. but when I copy-paste the SQL result by manul there is no date format issue happening. correct format is "2021-08-03 07:13:05.483"

Date format in SQL: 2021-08-03 07:13:05.483
Date format in excel: 03-08-2021  7.13.05 AM

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import datetime

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=xxxx;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx")

print("\nStarted data extraction from sql server..!\n")

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
     input_lines = [line.strip() for line in file]


with open('file_name.txt', 'r') as file:
     file_name_lines = [line.strip() for line in file]


for i, iter in zip(input_lines, file_name_lines):
    pd.read_sql(i,cnxn).to_excel('{}.xlsx'.format(iter), index=False)
    print(iter,' is Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the the cells that are displaying incorrectly, then click `Format Cells`, then click `Custom` and add this:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000
```

Now, it should be formatted according to the above pattern. This happens because SQL uses a different date format than MS Excel. See more [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e).

Answer (score 0):

Excel is using the date format of your Windows user profile.  If you want to change the default way that Excel displays dates then change your regional settings, otherwise do as suggested by @Theorist's answer above and custom-format the range of cells in the worksheet.  BTW the same applies to number and currency formatting - Excel does by default what it thinks you want, from the way your environment is set up.

Comment: Is there any possible way to solve this issue via sql query or python? because multiple people will use this script. in that case, changing the cell format or setting in excel for everyone is not a possible.

Comment: @Chandru: Unfortunately the answer is no.  This is not a Python problem or a SQL problem but an Excel problem.  Excel is getting the valid date as a date type and displaying it according to the user's environment settings.  That's a behaviour we can't change.  Your options are to find a way to explicitly set date formatting at cell level during spreadsheet creation or force the date data to a string (losing date arithmetic in Excel).  In Excel you would achieve this manually by entering `'2021-08-12...` (note the leading single quote).